# How make 2x4 fit under hanging studs that are too tight

Tags: basement, framing, framing-fasteners

Basement wall has cheap paneling on 2x4s hanging down from top but no longer anchored on concrete floor cause bottom 2x4 removed for new basement drainage trench install with new concrete over top. I got new ground contact 2x4s to put underneath and hopefully attach hanging studs to it. However, some new boards do not fit perfectly under, some have a gap (thats ok) but others are too about ¼" tight. What to do to make the boards fit, especially the tight ones, between the hanging studs and concrete floor?

Comment: Either cut studs or cut notches on bottom board.  Mark board where tight studs are.  Just notch enough to fit under, better just tight than loose.  Imagine panelling is still on wall.

Comment: Studs are wobbly so any ideas how to stabilize them (just 1 person) to make cutting easier...or is it easy to hold with 1 hand and cut with the other without danger of cutting my arm off? Yes paneling is "mostly" on wall except bottom 2' or so was cut off.

Comment: Would go with notching of bottom board.  Mark where notches go and then can notch in comfort.  Can cut the studs, but have the floor and wall right there in your way, plus them not being solidly mounted, equals no fun.  A hand saw compared to most power saws would be the best and safest for cutting studs.